# Use Go to read a file for use in javascript rendering

Tags: javascript, arrays, go

I have seen many articles about Go Arrays being used with Javascript but I am trying to do something a little different. I want to read a configuration file using Go, since it has access to the server side, and use it in a javascript function that will be rendered with the template. This is to avoid hard coding values in the JavaScript:

I want to change this:

```
javaString += "function isValidPrefix() {"
javaString += "forbidden_prefixes = [ \"1\", \"2\", \"3\", \"4\", \"5\", \"6\" ];"
... more javascript ...
javaString += "}"
```

to something that puts the prefixes in a file, so that I don't have to recompile every time I want to add a prefix.

So I tried this:

```
var configArr []string
configArr = LoadFile("/conf.dat")

javaString += "forbidden_prefixes = [];"

 for _, eachline := range configArr {
    javaString += "forbidden_prefixes.push(\" + eachline + \");"
    fmt.Println(eachline)
}
```

`eachLine` prints out correctly in the for loop but forbidden_prefixes contains one element `+ eachLine +` which I am assuming is a syntax error but even if I try to retrieve the DOM element's value to check it against, the web console says the element doesn't exist. Everything worked fine with the hardcoded values. Am I doing something wrong or is it simply just not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are building a string using literals, without using the variable you intended to use. Try this:

```
    javaString += fmt.Sprintf("forbidden_prefixes.push(\"%s\");",eachline)
```

Comment: This is susceptible to code injection. Use JSON encoding for safe output.

Answer (score 0):

The issue indeed comes from your syntax. You escaped the quotes so the `+` operators are actually part of the string. Here are two possible solutions:

```
javaString += "forbidden_prefixes.push(\"" + eachline + "\");"
```

Or

```
javaString += fmt.Sprintf("forbidden_prefixes.push(%q);", eachline)
```

`%q` adds quotes around the value it's replaced with.

Comment: The %q verb produces valid Go strings, not necessarily valid JavaScript strings. Use JSON encoding instead.